# C# - Why does new ZipArchive to MemoryStream fail where ZipArchive to FileStream works?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to setup a zip-download from an Azure Blob Storage. I've managed to create a valid FileStream, but when I try to do the same thing with a MemoryStream closing with .ToArray() the resulting .zip-file is corrupt.

Any ideas regarding what has gone wrong here is much appreciated!

### Code

```
[Route("test-download-zip")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<FileContentResult> TestDownloadZip()
{
    // Works
    await BlobLogic.DownloadZip_FileStream(Connections);

    // Fails
    byte[] bytes = await BlobLogic.DownloadZip_Bytes(Connections);

    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/zip")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "bytes.zip"
    };
}

public async Task DownloadZip_FileStream(IEnumerable<IBlobConnection> p_Connections)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("./test-data/");

    using FileStream s_ZipStream = new FileStream("./test-data/file-stream.zip", FileMode.Create);
    using ZipArchive s_ZipArchive = new ZipArchive(s_ZipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

    foreach (IBlobConnection connection in p_Connections)
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = s_ZipArchive.CreateEntry($"{Guid.NewGuid()}{connection.FileEnding}");

        CloudBlockBlob s_Block = GetBlockReference(connection);

        using Stream entrySteram = entry.Open();

        await s_Block.DownloadToStreamAsync(entrySteram);
    }
}

public async Task<byte[]> DownloadZip_Bytes(IEnumerable<IBlobConnection> p_Connections)
{
    using MemoryStream s_ZipStream = new MemoryStream();
    using ZipArchive s_ZipArchive = new ZipArchive(s_ZipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

    foreach (IBlobConnection connection in p_Connections)
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = s_ZipArchive.CreateEntry($"{Guid.NewGuid()}{connection.FileEnding}");

        CloudBlockBlob s_Block = GetBlockReference(connection);

        using Stream entrySteram = entry.Open();

        await s_Block.DownloadToStreamAsync(entrySteram);
    }

    s_ZipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return s_ZipStream.ToArray();
}
```

### Results

[image: FileStream works]

[image: Download bytes fails]

Comment: Does doing `s_ZipArchive.Flush()` before `s_ZipStream.ToArray()` fix it?

Comment: Try setting `Position` to 0 before calling `ToArray`. Or calling `s_ZipArchive.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`

Comment: I've tried: zipStream.Flush(); zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); zipStream.Position = 0;

With no result :(

Sry for the formatting, you are talking about zipStream and not the ZipArchive reference right?

Comment: `I've tried: zipStream.Flush(); zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); zipStream.Position = 0; With no result ` But have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: ZipArchive doesn't have .Flush() I think. I've tried zipStream.Flush() with no other modifications.

Comment: You are zipping the file twice.  The data stream you are receiving is in zip format.  So when you save the file with a zip extension the file is good.  When you create a new ZipArchive you are taking the zip stream and doing another zip.

Comment: Woah -- disposing the ZipArchive solved it for me! Thanks for putting me on the right track @Matthew Watson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disposing the ZipArchive before calling MemoryStream.ToArray() solved it for me. Thanks Matthew Watson :)

```
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadZip_Bytes(IEnumerable<IBlobConnection> p_Connections)
{
    using MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (IBlobConnection connection in p_Connections)
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry($"{Guid.NewGuid()}{connection.FileEnding}");

            CloudBlockBlob block = GetBlockReference(connection);

            using Stream entrySteram = entry.Open();

            await block.DownloadToStreamAsync(entrySteram);
        }
    }

    return zipStream.ToArray();
}
```